# Adverbial subordinate clause/ phrase

Tags: phrases, independent-clauses

> After March 2023, life will be back to normal.

Is the bit "After March 2020" an adverbial clause or a prepositional clause?

> After eight hours, they reached the peak.

Same doubt about "After eight hours".

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127689/discussion-on-question-by-res-adverbial-subordinate-clause-phrase).

Comment: Please **write answers.** Do not answer in comments. (The reason is that it allows @res to accept an answer and the system to note that the question is answered.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a prepositional phrase that adverbially modifies what ensues.

You're assuming it's one or the other, but that's a false assumption as prepositional phrases are modifying phrases, either adjectival or adverbial, and it just so happens that it's adverbial in your sentence. As such, it is **both** a prepositional phrase *and* an adverbial phrase there.

What it isn't is a subordinate clause, not adverbial or any other kind. In order to be a subordinate clause, it would have to contain a verb. It doesn't, so it's not.

For further information, you may refer to the following link and scroll down to the heading "Understand what prepositional phrases do in a sentence":

https://www.chompchomp.com/terms/prepositionalphrase.htm

Answer (score 3):

> *After March 2023, life will be back to normal.*

It's important to distinguish category and function.

"After" is a preposition so "after March 2023" can only belong to the category preposition phrase.

The PP is functioning as a modifier in clause structure, more specifically an adjunct, so we have:

Category: preposition phrase

Function: modifier (adjunct of time)

The same applies to your other example.

Note that the head word in a phrase determines its phrasal category (preposition phrase, adjective phrase, adverb phrase and so on).